# JPA (Hibernate) and Setup Entity Listener on Runtime

Tags: hibernate, jpa, runtime, entitylisteners

I have two projects:

- **beans.jar** with JPA entities (annotated for JSON/XML serialization) and `persistence.xml` file
- **rest.war** with REST application, where are JPA `EntityManagerFactory` instantiated with customized properties such as `hibernate.connection.*`

I want to distribute beans.jar for better client side programming convenience. So far good.

Some entities have code in `@PrePersist` event (salting password hash in fact), which I don't want to distribute. I can push that code to JPA entity listener, but listener class is referenced in `@EntityListeners` annotation and therefor must be in beans.jar as well.

Is it possible to **setup JPA entity listener for one (or all) entity classes on runtime**, i.e. in rest.war project?

Maybe there are some Hibernate property for this, which I overlooked...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sets up a generic EntityListener for all Entities.

Create a file named orm.xml and put it in the same directory as the persistence.xml file (e.g. META-INF).  I am not sure if this can be put in the war file.  The contents of the orm.xml file should be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit-metadata>
      <persistence-unit-defaults>
         <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="nathan.db.Listener"/>
         </entity-listeners>
      </persistence-unit-defaults>
   </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Then create a class called Listener.

```
package nathan.db;

import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

public class Listener
{
   @PrePersist
   public void event(Object entity)
   {
      // salt password
   }
}
```